# Detect touches for 2 subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UIView sitting atop a UIScrollView.

I'd like to be able to scroll my ScrollView normally while having my UIView catch:

`- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

The only issue is I cannot seem to get both subviews to detect touches at the same time. I can set the top one to `userInteractionEnabled` to NO. But that doesnt really help me get them both.

Any thoughts??

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In one of my project I catch touches in one view and pass the method to a second one this way:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    // Do something here

    [otherView touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

EDIT: You can also use a third UIView just to menage touches.

Put a third UIView on top of your views (it should be as wide as your screen) and let it menage your touches

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    // Get touch position
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    // Use location to pass touches to one view ot the other

    if (location == something) {
        [oneView touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    } else {
        [otherView touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, but if I have a UIView sitting ontop of a ScrollView, I won't be able to keep the same scrolling this way correct?

Comment: Well... I haven't tried this with UIScrollView, but I think it should work, just remember to override touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesCancelled as well. You could even put a third UIView on top of everything (youScreen.bound) just to menage touches... Take a look at my EDIT!!

Comment: Hmm this seems like it's pretty solid. but I'd like to detect both touches at the same time. So the scrolling is still enabled but also the touches began fire at the same time.

Comment: Then ,in the "if" you can pass the touch to one view and to both views... "if (location == viewOnTop) { [oneView touches...]; [otherView touches...] } else {[otherView touches...] }" This way your touches go to just one view (UIScrollView) or to both (topView and UIScrollView).

Comment: I really doubt this workaround would work on `UIScrollView`, because `UIScrollView` implement its scrolling feature by `UIPanRecognizerGesture`! You cannot have a gesture recognizer and `-touch...`methods work at the same time. @Beppe, have you tested this in a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: @liuyaodong If you read my first comment you'll see "Well... I haven't tried this with UIScrollView"

Comment: @Beppe but I think the point of the question is talking about, as @JamesDunay said, "I'd like to be able to scroll my ScrollView normally while having my UIView catch:...". Actually I tried your answer in a `UIScrollView` and it doesn't work.

Comment: My suggestion, as I wrote, was based on my experience with two UIView(s). If this solution doesn't fix the problem it is better NOT accept it!!